# Accidently removed cordova platform ios folder

Tags: ios

I was trying to uninstall a plugin but accidently ran the command `cordova platform remove ios` and it removed the app code on my macbook.

I don't see anything in trash as well. Is there any way to get the code back by reverse engineering on the ipa file?

Please help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about reverse-engineering.

Comment: @perror i clearly mentioned in the question that i lost the files. I asked that can we do reverse engineering to get the code back

Comment: Reverse-engineering what ? The file-system ? What you need is to recover erased files, it has nothing to do with reverse-engineering.

Comment: reverse engineering on the ipa file

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's not possible to recover 100% of source code from the binary but you may be able to get *some* things from it. See e.g.

- [Possibilities for reverse engineering an ipa file to its source](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/possibilities-for-reverse-engineering-an-ipa-file-to-its-source?rq=1)
- [Decompiling iPhone App](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4096/decompiling-iphone-app?rq=1)
- and so on.