# How does IDA apply its FLIRT signatures and how are they licenced?

Tags: ida, ghidra, flirt-signatures

I'm considering writing a Ghidra extension that would apply FLIRT signatures, but I'm not sure whether the license would support that, or whether FLIRT is dependent on inputs from IDA's architecture and analysis engine.

Does anyone know whether is technically and legally possible?

Comment: Helpful related answer: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175/what-is-a-flirt-signature